# ITunes connect show different behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

I have developer apple account , I try to publish my first application on apple store , I read some tutorial , I find out I muse log in Itunes connect and create application with my data

when I login into itunes connect I find this view

with link

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/gettingstarted

why get started ??

should be /ng/

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/

my account type organisation

any one face this problem

[image]

Comment: You can publish app by clicking on Apps button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this problem and it was caused because the team agent role was changed to someone else. So make sure that you're the team agent. You can check it on apple developer portal (member center -> people)
And you can change it by contacting apple support.

Comment: In my case I was already the team agent and still had the same problem. I think it was because my account was too recent. The solution was to send a message (using support tab in developer member center) requesting access to iTunes connect. I took 3 hours for them to reply and enable my access.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to publish an app, click on the blue app store logo to get started.

Comment: this behavior directs to tutorial, not to admin panel